# Angular momentum after elastic collision

Tags: angular-momentum, friction, collision

If two balls collide (elastically) and there is no friction between them, will their angular momentum change after the collision?

Comment: No. Without friction, the forces during the collision are applied exclusively through their centres of mass - hence there is no torque and hence the angular momentum cannot change. Wikipedia has a force diagram that illustrates what I mean: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Elastischer_sto%C3%9F_2D.gif

Comment: It doesn't even matter if energy is conserved.  A sufficient condition for angular momentum conservation is that the net external torque on the system of colliding particles is zero.

Comment: @joshphysics but in the presence of friction angular momentum might be transferred between the two

Comment: @m.buettner That's certainly true.  The question refers to "their angular momentum" which I interpreted to mean the angular momentum of the system consisting of both balls.  If that's not the case, then my comment is irrelevant.

Comment: @m.buettner that (your first comment) should be an answer :-)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky there you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without friction, the forces during the collision (glancing or head-on) are applied exclusively through their centres of mass. ([Illustration available on Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional))

The torque is given by $\tau=\mathbf r \times \mathbf F$ - but if the forces are applied through the centre of mass, then $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf F$ are parallel, and hence $\tau=0$.

Without a torque, angular momentum cannot change (because $\frac{\text{d}L}{\text{d}t}=\tau$), so that each ball will keep its angular momentum.

With friction, depending on the relative movement of the balls' surfaces during the collision, there could be a tangential component of the force, which would cause a torque on each ball. Therefore, angular momentum *could* be transferred. However, as joshphysics mentioned in a comment, the total angular momentum of the system would still be conserved, as there is no external net torque.